# Div position calc not working

Tags: html, css

I need to position the few divs as below. What I need is that the left div to take up full space minus 400 px just for the div resource. Now it overlaps on the left div. I can fix all of the width to be 400 but then on higher resolution there is big white space at the right. What is the best solution to this?

```
 <div id="left" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:calc(100%-400px);height:820px;background:#ececec;">
   <div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:calc(100%-400px);height:400px">Map goes here.</div>    
   <div id="asset" style="position:absolute;top:400px;left:0px;width:calc(100%-400px);height:420px;background:#ececec;">


   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="resource" style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:400px;left:calc(100%-400px);height:820px;background:#e6e6e6;">
   <table id="resourceHeading">
   </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think to use prefix ?

```
-moz-calc
-webkit-calc
-o-calc
```

etc...

You have also to make space before and after the minus :)

```
calc(100% - 400px)
```

Comment: You don't actually need prefixes for calc nowadays. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: What is moz-calc -webkit-calc -o-calc I am new to this I have tried to google on this not too good with these stuff.

Comment: Yes the space is the left div which have 2 div in it the map and asset details.

Comment: What I need is that for the resource id to have 400px as on the right and the map can be dynamic so that it can fill the entire page on different resolution

Comment: Your code is good, you need to make blank space after and before the - Like that : `width:calc(100% - 400px);`

Comment: I am confuse what space to be made I dont get you. The space is already occupied by the map supposedly right But the resource div keep appearing on the left side rather than on right side

Comment: in the code you wrote : calc(100%-400px) but it's calc(100% - 400px) ;)

Comment: Yes it works but unfortunately my map is so small now event my asset all shrink to right. But the resource now appear accordingly on the right column.  Do I need to put -moz-calc
-webkit-calc
-o-calc

Comment: Fabricio Matté told prefix are not nescessary :x

Comment: So what is prefix actually is this called prefix -moz-calc -webkit-calc -o-calc. Ok back to my problem now why does the map shrink. But now I put 100% - 200px its better kind of confuse here